# The stored procedure doesn't exist when calling SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm tring to get the parameters from a stored procedure but I am getting the error of

```
The stored procedure 'Generic.proc_UpdateGenericCatalog' doesn't exist.
```

The namespace Generic. is causing the error but I do not know which setting I should use to get beyond this error.

**--My Procedure--**

```
ALTER proc [Generic].[proc_UpdateGenericCatalog]
@UserID           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@Name             VARCHAR(30),
@SupplierName     VARCHAR(30),
@SupplierEmail    VARCHAR(50),
@SupplierPhone    VARCHAR(12),
@GenericCatalogID INT
AS

UPDATE [Generic].[GenericCatalog]
      SET [UserID] = @UserID
         ,[Name] = @Name
         ,[SupplierName] =  @SupplierName
         ,[SupplierEmail] = @SupplierEmail
         ,[SupplierPhone] = @SupplierPhone

 WHERE ID = @GenericCatalogID
```

**--The C# code I'm using to get the parameter info--**

**--The error is right here** `SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);`

How should I alter my code below so that I can get the .DeriveParameter info?

```
    private static SqlParameter[] DiscoverParameters(string connectionString, string spName)
    {
         SqlCommand cmd = null;
         SqlParameter[] discoveredParameters = null;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            { 

                conn.ConnectionString = connectionString; 
                conn.Open();

                cmd = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
                conn.Close();

                discoveredParameters = new SqlParameter[cmd.Parameters.Count];

                cmd.Parameters.CopyTo(discoveredParameters, 0);

                foreach (SqlParameter discoveredParameter in discoveredParameters)
                {
                    discoveredParameter.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
        return discoveredParameters;
    }
```

Comment: Try passing just `proc_UpdateGenericCatalog` as spName, not `Generic.proc_GetProfilesByGroup`

Comment: I did and that did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the user specified in your connection string doesn't have permission to execute the `Generic.proc_UpdateGenericCatalog` procedure. I've just tested on one of my databases, and if the user doesn't have `EXEC` permission you'll get the "stored procedure doesn't exist" error.

Also, you should probably be cloning the parameters, rather than just copying them to an array. This is quite easy to do with a bit of LINQ:

```
private static SqlParameter[] DiscoverParameters(string connectionString, string spName)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection))
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        connection.Open();
        SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
        connection.Close();

        return command.Parameters
            .Cast<ICloneable>()
            .Select(p => p.Clone())
            .Cast<SqlParameter>()
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not it either.

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com: Are you sure? I've just tried on my local instance with that exact procedure name and parameter list, and it works perfectly. What happens if you try to execute the procedure without specifying any parameters using the same connection string?

Comment: I had on rouge procedure that was named [dbo].[Generic].[proc_MyProcedure]. that [dbo] part was messaging everything up.